# Why do I have an error when taking a Part of an indexed List?

Tags: functions

Sometimes I get an error, sometimes I don't.

````
For[i = 1, i <= 27, i++, tm[i] = Tuples[{0, .5, 1}, 3]];

For[i = 2, i <= 27, i++, k = 0;
 For[j = 1, j <= 27, j++, tm[i][[28]] = tm[i][[1]]; k = k + 1; 
  tm[i][[j]] = tm[i][[k]] ] ]
```
````

Comment: `Tuples[{0, .5, 1}, 3] // Dimensions` is `{27, 3}` so part 28 does not exist. `tm[i][[28]]`